# Trabalhar com ambientes em javascript utilizando Grunt

Tags: javascript, grunt, deploy, yeoman

Tenho um problema muito ruim em meus projetos web, eu não trabalho com ambientes, eu queria que minha aplicação tivesse diferentes tipos de configuração de acordo com o ambiente, por exemplo: no ambiente DEV meu aplicativo acessa um servidor e no ambiente PROD ele acessa outro. Para isso eu teria que ter uma tarefa no Grunt que alterasse variáveis no meu script ao fazer o deploy, alguém sabe como fazer isso ?

Esse é o meu [Gruntfile](https://github.com/fabioelizandro/todas-as-patas-app/blob/master/Gruntfile.js)

Comment: Utilizar [variáveis de ambiente](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vari%C3%A1vel_de_ambiente) não soluciona seu problema? Você pode acessar elas usando `process.env.VARIAVEL`.

Comment: Não, são configurações do meu script que vai rodar no navegador.

Comment: Ah, claro. Bem, de qualquer forma, não tem como passar as configurações para dois arquivos `.js` separados (`config-dev.js` e `config-prod.js`, por exemplo) e definir quando utilizar cada um no `Gruntfile.js`?

Comment: Poderia postar seu `Gruntfile.js`?

Comment: @gabrielhof coloquei o link na minha pergunta

Comment: Uma última pergunta, você quer acessar esses servidores via AJAX? Caso sim, você pretende usar JSONP pra isso?

Comment: Vai ser um aplicativo HTML5 consumindo um Webservice PHP. E não utilizo JSONP só JSON

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17078/discussion-between-gabrielhof-and-fabio-lemos-elizandro).

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso utilizo o grunt-replace para fazer o replace das variáveis de configuração.

[Plugin de replace do grunt](https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace)